# No AuthenticationProvider found for SAMLAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using SSOCircle as IDP provider and using spring SAML. I have logged into SSOCircle and created a new SP and configured the unique entityID in securityContext.xml

I am able to see idp selection page but not able to see the login page. the configuration which is added are as follows

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">  
  <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <constructor-arg value="/conf/spring_saml_metadata.xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                       <property name="local" value="true"/>
                       <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>
                       <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix"/>
                       <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
                       <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                       <property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                       <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/>
                       <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                       <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                       <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                       <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                       <property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="http://localhost:8080/myApp/saml/discovery"/>
                       <property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="http://localhost:8080/myApp/saml/login?disco=true"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">15000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
    </list></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Entity ID is configured as mentioned below

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <!-- <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:user:city"/> -->
            <property name="entityId" value="urn:myApp:useruser:dub"/>
            <property name="requestSigned" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The exception is below

```
 org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationToken
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:196)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that your `AuthenticationProvider` is missing instance of the `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider`, make sure that your `securityContext.xml` contains definition of the SAML auhentication provider, similar to the following:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue and I added my `samlAutheticationProvider` in spring xml as stated by @Vladimir. I still got the same exception. When I debugged the code and logged the authentication managers available, I couldn't find my new saml authentication manager.
When I added the "id" in the `security:authentication-manager`, it worked fine.

```
<security:authentication-manager  alias="samlAuthenticationManager" id="samlAuthenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Hope this helps.